# How to create complete page using html template

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am new to typo3 and hope someone can help.

My goal is to create a complete page on my server using free template I have downloaded [this one](https://bootstrapmade.com/flattern-multipurpose-bootstrap-template/). I wouldn't like to start from scratch.

After that I have extractet the content and added to fileadmin/templates (I have created directory templates in fileadmin)

After that I have created a root page in typo3 backend and added this code in order to bind the downloaded template:

```
page = PAGE
page{
bodyTag=<body>
meta.AUTHOR= ALSHADADI
10 = TEMPLATE
10.template= FILE
10.template.file = fileadmin/templates/index.html 
10.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT
  
includeCSS{
  screen= fileadmin/templates/assets/css/style.css  
screen.title= display
  screen.media = screen
}
}
```

[image]

Now when I retrieve the page - after clear cache - , it shows nothing (no error message or any content). Any Idea what I did wrong or how I should better do? I am using typo3 version 9.5.14

Comment: You should give the Introduction Distribution give a chance to get an overview see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/Distributions/Index.html

Comment: @SimonGilli sounds good thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your template is not a template TYPO3 can use without further work.

You need to differ the concept and wording.

A `template` is a pattern for something to be build in a similar way.

In the world of TYPO3 there exists multiple things called `template`.

1. the records with typoscript which define a way how data is rendered to a HTML page
2. two kinds/ ways of HTML similar files where some replacements are done to render data in a HTML mark-up.

   a) the 'old' way (you have referenced): "marker-templates". where markers or subparts (between two markers) are replaced with something build by typoscript (but I doubt that those files contain matching markers)

   b) "Fluid-templates" with some logic to control the building. you have data in variables and you have viewhelpers, which modify data or control the rendering. (similar to Smarty-Templates)

Additional to the HTML mark-up you need CSS and maybe javascript, which might be the main part of the template you get from that site.

If your template (mark-up example and CSS/JS) is based on twitter bootstrap you could use a TYPO3-package/extension which renders TYPO3 pages with a bootstrap mark-up, then add your CSS and JS.

The easiest way (there is no easy way to get a TYPO3 running without learning a lot about TYPO3) might be:

**Install TYPO3 and the bootstrap-Package from Benjamin Kott.**
**Then add the CSS and JS from your retrieved template.**

If you are lucky the template uses plain bootstrap mark-up which is provided with the package of Benjamin. This also gives you the complete range of content elements of bootstrap. After adding the CSS all styling should be adapted.

**If you are lucky.**
I doubt it and that would require that you know a lot more about TYPO3. That can't be given in a stackoverflow answer.
Get a book and/or read the documents from https://docs.typo3.org

Comment: Ok these are good informations but I still have no Idea how this answer could help me to solve the problem :)

Comment: no simple way. maybe my answer is a little bit clearer now.